# Why can an initializer-list not be used as an argument?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct X
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

int f(X x)
{
    return x.a + x.b;
}

int main()
{
    int n = f({1, 2});
}
```

Visual Studio 2012 (Nov CTP) reports:

```
error C2664: 'int f(const X &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
'initializer-list' to 'X'

Reason: cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'X'
Only an initializer-list with zero or one elements can be converted to this type

Build FAILED.
```

Comment: Clang 3.1 and g++ 4.7.2 compiles this code without any errors.

Comment: Then this seems a bug of VC++, though it declared that it has suppoted this feature.

Comment: VC++ is known to be broken at diverse parts

Comment: @xmllmx : The Community Technology Preview is, well, a _preview_. Think alpha-quality, and _expect_ bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Visual Studio 2012 (Nov CTP) reports:

It's not even a *beta* compiler. It's supposed to work. I'd link to your code working on ideaone, but this website won't let be do that.

File a bug report on it.

Comment: BTW, here's the [Ideaone link](http://ideone.com/05feuD) the site wouldn't let me use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass intializer list style syntax to your constructor then you have to pass a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) type to your constructor.  This type will then construct an array of your types when passed a `{ }` syntax style construct.

Comment: I think this style is pretty expressive. Why did the standard not support it?

Comment: If I must add a constructor, then X is no longer a POD type, which is just what I want.