# error C2664 - cannot convert parameter 1 from 'initializer-list' to 'const QList<QCommandLineOption> &'

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I downloaded some code and run it in VS2013+QT5.4, there is code like this:

```
parser.addOptions({
        { "nogui", QString("Using command line arguments, do not show GUI.") },
        { { "p", "path" }, QString("Path for job files or shape files."), QString("path") },
    });
```

and I got an error:

```
error C2664 - cannot convert parameter 1 from 'initializer-list' to 'const QList<QCommandLineOption> &'
```

It seems about a VS problem of C++11?...and I wonder how to fix it?

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013135/why-can-an-initializer-list-not-be-used-as-an-argument. It might be helpful to you.

Comment: Did you install updates for Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: @MarkoPopovic No. Should I install updates?

Comment: @H.A I suggest you do because updates for VC++ compiler might resolve this issue.